# C++ ownership of a function parameter

Tags: c++, ownership

I wrote a function which has this form:

`Result f( const IParameter& p);`

My intention is that this signature will make it clear that the function is not taking ownership of the parameter `p`.

Problem is that `Result` will keep a reference to `IParameter`:

```
class Result
{  
    const IParameter& m_p;

public: 
    Result( const IParameter& p ) 
        : m_p( p ){ } 
};
```

But then it happened that somebody called the function like this:

`const auto r = f(ConcreteParameter{});`

Unfortunately the temporary can be bound to const reference, and this caused a crash.

Question is: how can I make it clear that the function is not supposed to be called with temporaries, and maybe have a nice compilation error when that happens? Is it actually wrong in this case to state that it is not taking the ownership, since is passing it to result that will be propagated outside the function call scope?

Comment: The wisdom of such an interface is questionable. The ownership semantics are very unclear. I've done this sort of thing myself, but I cringe when I do it (so that makes it OK!).  I would suggest following the GSL and just have the function take a bare pointer and comment that ownership of the pointer is not taken and it must not be `nullptr`. Though, I believe the GSL specifies that bare pointer parameters are non-owning. https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ri-raw

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to make it clear is to overload the function with an rvalue reference parameter.  Those are prefered to const references for temporaries so they will be chosen instead.  If you then delete said overload, you'll get a nice compiler error.  For your code that would look like:

```
Result f( const IParameter&& ) = delete;
```

You can also do the same thing with `Result` to gaurd it as well and that would look like:

```
class Result
{  
    const IParameter& m_p;

public: 
    Result( const IParameter& p ) 
        : m_p( p ){ } 
    Result( const IParameter&& ) = delete;
};
```

Comment: `const IParameter&&` is the `const` intentional?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Yes.  You can make const temporaries so it wouldn't catch those without it.  It would then fall back to the const reference overload which you don't want.

Comment: @MarekR Doh.  I'll add that.

Comment: I really disagree that this answer solve OP's problem. But your explanation is nice.

Comment: [Live prove of concept](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CeZjjXIbqvP5XwI0).

Comment: How do you create a const temporary? Yes, i know you can create it by hand, but it takes a lot of work and i dont think you can create one by accident.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski If you have a alias for a const type, like `using c_bar = const bar;`, then `c_bar{}` is a constant temporary.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think your answer clarified the problem to me. So it is correct to assume there is no ownership being taken but to workaround the language possibility of associating temporaries to const references, I need in this case to explicitly delete the unfortunate unwanted overload. What I do not understand is the constness of the rvalue reference, since without it I see the same effect... can you explain more about why it is required?

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 The constness is there as an extra guarantee.  It is possible to create a constant temporary.  If you do have one of those, then the plain rvalue reference won't bind to that since it is not const.  That means the const reference overload would be picked and would leave you with a dangling reference.  Adding the const to the rvalue reference prevents that as a const rvalue reference will bind to const and non const temporary.

Answer (score 3):

You can manually remove a constructor accepting an `IParameter&&` rvalue from the overload set:

```
class Result
{
    // ...

    public:
    Result( IParameter&& ) = delete; // No temporaries!
    Result( const IParameter& p );
};
```

When client code tries to instantiate an object via

```
Result f(ConcreteParameter{}); // Error
```

the constructor taking a `const`-qualified reference is no match because of the missing `const`-ness, but the rvalue constructor exactly matches. As this one is `= delete`d, the compiler refuses to accept such an object creation.

Note that as pointed out in the comments, this can be circumvented with `const`-qualified temporaries, see [@NathanOliver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56651592/9593596) for how to make sure this doesn't happen.

Also note that not everyone agrees that this is good practice, have a look [here](https://youtu.be/2UmDvg5xv1U?t=920) (at 15:20) for example.

Comment: Do note this is subtly broken.  It wont catch constant temporaries.  See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df5f6b7770b5367d

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the link, I didn't have that in my mind. Let me refer to your comment in the answer...

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell. The best way would be to document that `Result` must not live longer than the `IParameter` used to construct it.

There are valid cases of temporaries sent as constructor that is perfectly valid. Think about this:

```
doSomethingWithResult(Result{SomeParameterType{}});
```

Deleting the constructor taking temporaries would prevent such valid code.

Also, deleting the rvalue constructor won't prevent all cases. Think about this:

```
auto make_result() -> Result {
    SomeParameterType param;
    return Result{param};
}
```

Even if the constructor with temporary is deleted, invalid code is still really easy to make. You *will* have to document the lifetime requirement of your parameters anyways.

So if you have to document such behavior anyways, I would opt for what the standard library does with [string views](https://godbolt.org/z/za7cXF):

```
int main() {
    auto sv = std::string_view{std::string{"ub"}};
    std::cout << "This is " << sv;
}
```

It won't prevent constructing string views from temporary strings since it can be useful, just like my first example.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if a function receives value by `const&`, it's expected, that the function will use the value, but won't hold it. You do hold the reference to value so you should probably change argument type to use `shared_ptr` (if the resource is mandatory) or `weak_ptr` (if resource is optional). Otherwise you'll run into that kind of problems from time to time, as no one reads documentation.

Comment: I agree.  The real problem is that the class **is** holding onto the object, and that impacts the lifespan of the held object.  The class "is not taking the ownership" is incorrect.  The class should either make its own copy of the IParameter, or it should be passed in a shared_ptr (explicitly being allowed to partake of federated ownership), or be passed in a unique_ptr (explicitly being allowed to assume ownership).  Anything else is very fragile, and will be hard to debug.

Comment: Exactly, this is why i posted this answer. Others are - at best - fragile, as you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

I already voted @NathanOliver answer as the best one, because I really think it is given the information I provided. On the other hand I would like to share what I think is a better solution to solve this very specific scenario when the function is more complex than the one in my initial example.

The problem with the `delete` solution is that it grows exponentially with the number of parameters, assuming that all the parameters needs to stay alive after the function call ends and you want a compile time check that the user of your API is not trying to give the ownership of those parameters to the function:

```
void f(const A& a, const B& b)
{
    // function body here
}

void f(const A& a, B&& b) = delete;
void f(A&& a, const B& b) = delete;
void f(A&& a, B&& b) = delete;
```

We need to `delete` all the possible combination, and this will be hard to maintain on the long run. So my proposed solution is to take advantage of the fact that the `reference_wrapper` constructor which wraps `T` by move is already deleted in STD, and then write this:

```
using AConstRef = reference_wrapper<const A>;
using BConstRef = reference_wrapper<const B>;

void f(AConstRef a, BConstRef b)
{
    // function body here
}
```

In this way all the invalid overload will be automatically deleted. I do not see any drawback with this approach so far.