# C++How to properly create n objects of a class with own Access class?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a class Entity which contains some data in a vector (_vec) and a another class which purpose it is to create some individual access to the data. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Access{
public:
    Access(std::vector<double>& data) : _vec(data) {}

    double& operator[](size_t i) {
        return _vec[i];
    }
private:
    std::vector<double>& _vec;
};


class Entity {
public:
    Entity(size_t n) : _data(n), accessName(_data) {}
    std::vector<double> _data;
    Access accessName;
};
```

I can easily create one object of the class Entity with a vector of length 4 like this:

```
    Entity versionScalar(4);
    versionScalar.accessName[0] = 1;
    
    for (const auto & e :versionScalar._data) {
        std::cout << e << ", ";
    }
    std::cout <<"\n";
```

and use my Access class to manipulate the vector _vec. As supposed the output will be: 1, 0, 0, 0,

To do the same thing with multiple objects I tried this:

```
    std::vector<Entity> versionVec(2, 4);
    versionVec[0].accessName[0] = 1;
    
    for (const auto & e : versionVec[0]._data) {
        std::cout << e << ", ";
    }
    std::cout <<"\n";
```

However here is the output: 0, 0, 0, 0,. So my Access isn't working any more correctly. How to properly create n objects of class Entity?

Comment: My attempt at duplicating your problem falls over and dies (https://godbolt.org/z/cYWWTzj1T) so I want to make absolutely certain we're both looking at the same bug before proceeding. This is one of the many reasons you want to supply a [mre].

Comment: @user4581301 Possible inspiration? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651525/c-ownership-of-a-function-parameter

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for your quick response. I am actually confused about that error on the compiler explorer, the code works correctly on onlinegdb (https://onlinegdb.com/dr6zhKwqb)

Comment: @dai detects and reports the problem at compile time. Definitely a good preventative, but how do we dig the asker out of this hole?

Comment: @user4581301 Using a very _Rusty_ shovel...

Comment: _"and a another class which purpose it is to create some individual access to the data"_ <-- Ditch your `class Access` - it doesn't solve any problems.

Comment: Here's a step-by-step showing you what happened: https://godbolt.org/z/h5djarnhn See the temporary being constructed and copied into both items in `versionVec` followed by its demise? And then the dead temporary `Entity`'s `data` is till being used?

Comment: Better example: https://godbolt.org/z/49xb6PTG9 Now you can see how the copied `Access`s `_vec`s don't refer to their containing `Entity`'s `_data`s. This <expletive deleted> is just ugly. Don't do it.

Comment: Side note: because a reference cannot be reseated (made to reference a different variable) reference members make a mess out of assignment operators and `vector` does a lot of assigning as you add, remove and generally move its contents around.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for your helpful answers. However I still dont get why there is the copy constructor called/involved? What I was intending is to construct n objects of Entity with their relating Access classes, not copying any one. Like the scalar code does, it just creates one Entity class and one Acess class and destroys it after main scope ends. Should it not be possible to have this n times and store does own objects in a vector of which i can iterate over?

Comment: @PyOPTProblem dynamic sized vectors work by constantly allocating bigger chunks of memory and moving the data in the old chunk to the newer chunk on inesrtions, if you are okay with deleting the copy/move consturctors of your `Entity` class, you can instead use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::vector<Entity>>>` to be able to store non-movable objects, with the obvious side-effect of the extra heap allocation, the whole pattern is wasteful in terms of performance and memory.

Comment: @Ahmed AEK thank you for your answer. What whould be the other solution that you mentioned in your post below? Makeing Copy and move constructor doing deep copys? And how would that be in terms of performance/memory? Unfortunately I can not use your soltion below, because the access pattern in my code requires to call accessName without parentheses (like variables)

Comment: @PyOPTProblem something like this https://godbolt.org/z/78n8KzGn7 , this has big maintenance cost terms of complexity, each time you add another member to `Entity` you must modify the copy/move operations to accommodate it, but in terms of memory you only lose those 8 bytes of the reference.

Comment: What happens is `std::vector<Entity> versionVec(2, 4);`, to avoid having to create multiple `Entity`s, creates one `Entity`, and then copies the sucker into all of the slots in the `vectior`. After that, pratty much everything you do to manipulate the vectopr will copy, move , or assign the existing `Entity`s in the `vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as pointed by the fellow programmers in the comments, the reference in `Access` doesn't get "fixed" when the parent `Entity` is copied/moved, you could implement the copy/move constructors but this is not an optimal solution.

something that i found useful for "access" classes is to make them act as temporaries, basically

```
class Access{
public:
    Access(std::vector<double>& data) : _vec(data) {}    
    double& operator[](size_t i) && { // only on temporaries
        return _vec[i];
    }
    // maybe add a begin() and end()
private:
    std::vector<double>& _vec;
};


class Entity {
public:
    Entity(size_t n) : _data(n) {}
    std::vector<double> _data;
    Access accessName() {return Access{_data};}
};
```

to be used this way

```
versionVec[0].accessName()[0] = 1;
```

if you put this Access class completely in the header then the compiler will [optimize it out on -O0](https://godbolt.org/z/bb1obh6K7), and the only way to misuse this class is to do something like this.

```
Acces obj = versionVec[0].accessName(); // deliberate extension of temporary
Entity other = std::move(versionVec[0]); // obj._vec is now empty
std::move(obj)[0] = 1;
```

Edit: a complete `Access` class with const and non-const overloads will look as follows https://godbolt.org/z/hdTYrdhWo